# How can I disable slow scrolling in gnome apps?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, scrolling, gtk

This happens GTK apps such as `gedit` and `evince`. Occasionally if I hold a scrollbar down too long without scrolling really fast it goes into a slow mode and becomes useless. How can I disable the slow-scrolling mode?

[image]

<sup><sup>(because posts are always better with images)</sup></sup>

I find this quite frustrating because I have a decent dpi mouse and often I'm slowly scrolling while reading and then want to quickly jump to another place in the file but find I can't and have to re-click.

There's a post about it [here](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2013/08/05/scrolling-in-gtk/) with a [video](https://mclasen.fedorapeople.org/scrolling.webm) showing the effect.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7705894.html),

1. Edit/create-if-does-not-exist: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`
2. Add the lines:

   ```
   [Settings] 
   gtk-long-press-time = 5000
   ```